# Create AMP page in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amp-html

I am trying to create an AMP project using Asp.net MVC 5. After putting all things correctly I still get error as below in AMP validator.
[image]

Comment: Is Javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: no it is not enabled..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use text/javascript in AMP pages. AMP pages has their own style tags. We can not use inline style to AMP pages. The content written within  tag has to be minified.

Answer (score 2):

I found creating a valid AMP page was difficult so took the time to create a website that creates a basic valid AMP template. Once created add and amend content until it breaks the rectify the errors.

I found three validation methods and the best was to add this Chrome, Opera or Vivaldi extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?hl=en

Pages are validated in the background and valid, warnings or errors shown by green, amber or red icons.

AMP template creator:

https://www.amppagemaker.com/